# subfigures overlaping

Tags: subfloats, overlap

I have 7 images which I need to display by pairs using subfigures environment, but each subfigures overlap and hide some of the uper captions as in the image :
[image]

Here is the tex code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LaTeX.jpg}
    \caption{Titre image 1}
    \label{img1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latex.jpg}
    \caption{Titre image 2}
    \label{img2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latex.jpg}
    \caption{Titre image 3}
    \label{img3}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latex.jpg}
    \caption{Titre image 4}
    \label{img4}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latex.jpg}
    \caption{Titre image 5}
    \label{img5}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latex.jpg}
    \caption{Titre image 6}
    \label{img6}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latex.jpg}
    \caption{Titre image 7}
    \label{img7}
\end{subfigure}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Titre global}
\label{global}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So how can I fix this please ?
Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me if I use the `draft` option or if I replace all images by `example-image`.

Comment: Is there any other packages that can affect this code ?

Comment: The point of @leandriis is: We do not have `latex.jpg` to reproduce your problem. Using publicly available file `example-image` created by @MartinScharrer or suppressing all images by the `draft` class option, your problem simply does not appear. **Not related**: You may want to write `\end{subfigure}%` instead of `\end{subfigure}` before issuing `\hfill`, or just `\end{subfigure}\hfill` in the same row. Since now you only have two images in one row, this will not be any different. But if you have more, it may have surprising side-effect.

Comment: @HindDev: Finding out if the problem is caused by a piece of code that you did not show is nearly impossible. You can easily find out if the problem is caused by your images or by a package you load, by (a) replacing your real images by `example-image` and see if the problem persists (b) stepwise comment out packages of your real preamble untill you see the problem disappears.

Comment: Also, try showframe and figure [p] instead of [H].

Comment: @leandriis I disagree. We know the problem is caused by a piece of code the OP didn't show. What is nearly impossible is to guess which piece of code that might be. ;)

Comment: @cfr: Thanks for the clarification. This is what I actually wanted to express with my comment.